# add trailing values to the string

Tags: apex, string

I have multiple currency/percent fields on which I need a method to add Zeros at the end. for example I have a currency(18,2) with value 4590, should end as  4590.00. percent(3,3) with value 3.3 should be 3.300. I need a reusable method which does this. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Where are you wanting to do this? In Visualforce page?

Comment: @Eric : In apex for string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about displaying it on a VF page you can use one of these:

```
<apex:outPutText value="{0,number,currency}">
   <apex:param value="{!YOURFIELD}"/>
</apex:outPutText>
```

or to control decimal places:

```
<apex:outPutText value="{0,number,$#,###.000}">
   <apex:param value="{!YOURFIELD}"/>
</apex:outPutText>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

for a string in apex simply do this:

```
public static string formatInteger(Integer i, integer places){
   if(i == null) return '';
   return formatDecimal(decimal.valueOf(i));
}

public static string formatDecimal(Decimal d, Integer places){

   if(d == null || places == null) return '';

   d.setScale(places);
   return string.valueOf(d);

}
```